# Images on webpage not visible on Chrome 78 on Android 8/9 (but work on Chrome 76, and Android 10) - what could be wrong?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I've got a little tool to work out your favorite Pokémon, located [here](https://www.dragonflycave.com/favorite.html). For a little while now, I've been getting intermittent report from users that the images aren't working - they're just seeing empty gray circles. Long story short, they all seem to be using Chrome on Android, and I've confirmed with some friends with Android phones that it's not working for them either, using Chrome 78 on Android 8 or 9.

However, it's working fine for another friend using the same Chrome on Android 10, and on my husband's phone (Android 6), where Chrome hadn't been updated in a bit and was still on version 76, it was also working *until* he just now updated it to 78 (at which point his phone immediately began to have the same problem). Chrome 78 on my iPhone, or on my laptop, works fine.

If I manually open the direct link to one of the images on his phone post-update, that works fine, so presumably it's not having trouble *loading* the images (which would have been weird anyway, as they're hosted on the same domain).

Looking back through my e-mail at the reports I've gotten, the first one appears to be from October 12th, with Chrome 77 being released in September, so it seems plausible that the issue first appeared there.

However, I'm kind of at a loss as to how to approach this. What might have changed in Chrome 77, on Android <10 only, that could be causing this, and what could be done to fix it? I don't think I'm doing anything terribly weird on that page; this is the CSS that's applied to the relevant elements:

```
.item-list li {
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    height:106px;
    width:106px;
    border:3px solid transparent;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:100%;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}

.item-list li span {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:3px;
    background:#F7F7F7;
    border-radius:100%;
}

.item-list li img {
    position:absolute;
    top:-7px;
    left:-11px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or have you been able to reproduce on Android 8/9 (i.e. reproduction steps). If you have been able to replicate the problem you can check with [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) to see if anything looks off.

Comment: @MorrisonChang The reproduction steps are simply visiting the linked webpage on Chrome on Android - below the text at the top, there'll be a grid of gray circles. There should be images in the circles. Thanks for the link, I'll check that out.

Comment: You probably should list which devices the error occurs. I just tried the site with Chrome for Android 78.0.3904.108 on a Samsung S9 running Android 9/One UI version 1.0 on WiFi using US internet and I saw gray circles only as the characters images loaded, and all of the images appeared to load.

Comment: Works fine on the latest Chrome on Galaxy S9 (Pie) India

Comment: All right, I've now used remote debugging to inspect the page, and what's going on seems to be about Chrome's native lazy-loading of images. I noticed the console had the message "[Intervention] Images loaded lazily and replaced with placeholders. Load events are deferred." Turns out by enabling or disabling native lazy loading in chrome://flags, then restarting Chrome, I can reliably trigger or resolve the issue on the same device. What a pain. (Note that the images don't have loading="lazy" or anything of the kind; they should not be lazy-loaded. How do I turn it off?)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was about Chrome's new [native lazy-loading of images](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5645767347798016), which for some reason was preventing these images from loading even though they were visible and above the fold. As far as I'm concerned this just plain looks like a bug in Android Chrome. Manually enabling or disabling lazy loading under chrome://flags would trigger or resolve the issue, even on the exact same device.

By manually adding `loading="eager"` on the image tags, I could force Chrome to load the images anyway even when the feature is enabled, solving the issue. I hope to be able to create a minimal test case to be able to file a bug about this and get it actually fixed at the source.